# Insufficient privileges on View Source in SonarQube 5.1

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.1

I have encountered an issue on SQ (SonarQube)5.1 in 'View Source' functionality.

On SQ 5.1 I am not able to view the source code of any file on one of the project. However all other project/s seems to be working fine on this.

I have the admin credentials and I checked the setting -> permissions on both of these projects. 'BROWSE' and 'SEE SOURCE CODE' configs have 'Anyone' value for the Groups.

But view source does not work (with Admin or without logging in) on a specific project - SQ throws "Insufficient privileges" popup error on a browser (http 403 Forbidden)

I am wondering where is the issue? a known bug with SQ 5.1 ?

appreciate any help in debugging this issue!

Comment: Have you recently migrated to 5.1? And have you recently analysed this project?

Comment: Oh I see what you mean.. Yes I have migrated to 5.1 recently and I am seeing that the project with the permission issue was last run on the same day. I will ask the team to re run the analysis again. That will possibly resolve the issue. Wondering how the project permission would affect with the SQ version upgrade..

Comment: @Fabrice-SonarSourceTeam I deleted the project from SQ and re ran the analysis, however its still having the privilege issue. Is there anything in the way we run the analysis .. anything in maven command? I am debugging more..

Comment: This is really weird that you have the problem with only this project. When the project is processed on the server, you don't see any error in the logs? What does the "Settings > System > Analysis Reports" page shows for this project?

Answer (score 1):

You need `See Source Code` permissions - you can change those by going to `Administration -> Projects -> Management -> Edit Permissions` and edit those.

[image: SonarQube Group Permissions]

P.S. I know it's 5 years later, but this still applies to the current version of SonarQube ‍♂️